# In Prolog, predicate

Tags: prolog, functor

Is the following Prolog goal satisfactory?

```
croire(X, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza))?
```

I have found a Prolog document asking that question and the answer was: " No, this goal is syntactically incorrect" but when I tried it in SWI-Prolog, it didn't show any error and it gave me this as an answer which I find logical:

```
X = ali,
Y = lila.
```

So is there something that I've missed? Or is the document answer is just wrong?

Comment: Can you post a link to the document claiming this?

Comment: I think this seems to deal with *epistemic logic*. which is a form of logic that *can* be emulated in Prolog, but can require some additional infrastructure.

Comment: It is in French, would that be okay with you?

Comment: the question mark is what make it syntactically incorrect

Comment: @CapelliC since the OP ran it and got results, I assumed that was just a notational error in the question. But if the referenced (but not shown) text really did include a question mark as part of the entered syntax, then it would indeed be wrong.

Answer (score 3):

Foremost, the query is also satisfiable in GNU Prolog (please note that Prolog queries always end with a dot, not a question mark):

```
GNU Prolog 1.4.4 (64 bits)
Compiled Aug  3 2017, 08:15:35 with gcc
By Daniel Diaz
Copyright (C) 1999-2013 Daniel Diaz
| ?- croire(X, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza)).

X = ali
Y = lila

(1 ms) yes
```

So what does it mean? We ask if there is an assignment for the variables `X` and `Y`, such that the term `croire(X, aime(lila, pizza))` and `croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza))` are equal. GNU Prolog returns an answer, namely `X = ali, Y = lila`. Let's see what terms we obtain when we apply this substitution:

`croire(ali, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(lila, pizza))`

Since a term is certainly equal to itself, this substitution satisfies the equality predicate. On the other hand, `X = reine, Y = grenouille` leads to

```
croire(reine, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(grenouille, pizza))
```

which is -- without further assumptions -- false.

Remark: I find the term satisfiable in this context quite confusing. Even though I should know better, I am still struggling for a good description of what's going on, but I will try:

Prolog's inference mechanism is resolution which aims at deriving a contradiction, but a contradiction is an unsatisfiable formula. In this particular case, we resolve `Z != Z` with `croire(X, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza))` to obtain the (unsatisfiable) empty clause.

If we write down the clause set in a positive way, it looks like this:

```
∀Z (Z=Z) ⊃ ∃X ∃Y (croire(X, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza)))
```

Pulling the quantifiers to the front, we obtain:

```
∃Z ∃X ∃Y ( Z=Z ⊃  (croire(X, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza))) )
```

Now, if `Z=Z ⊃  (croire(X, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(Y, pizza)))` is satisfiable, then its existential closure is valid. I find it very hard to be precise in this manner and usually just speak of an answer (substitution) for the query. Then I can call the clause set obtained by applying the answer substitution unsatisfiable without getting confused.

Comment: You have a little mixup in you counterexample: The substitutions `X = reine, Y = grenouille` lead to `croire(reine, aime(lila, pizza)) = croire(ali, aime(grenouille, pizza)).` ;-)

Comment: You are completely right, thank you! The mistake should be fixed now. Also thanks to @false for correcting my french spelling.

Comment: Logically speaking, a query is first negated. If a refutation for the negated query is found, it means that the positive (original) query is satisfiable!

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Completeness_(logic)#Refutation_completeness expresses it nicely. It boils down to: Robinson's resolution on clause sets is not strongly complete, but it is refutation-complete.